# NoClassDefFoundError at Google Play Services V2 library

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I get the following exception when trying to use the Google Play Services V2 library after following the [official tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start).

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(Unknown Source)
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Did you provide Google android apiKey to your application? Please, provide info about your Manifest.xml and snippets of code where you got Exception

Comment: I didn't my ID to the application, yet. IMO failing with an unrelated error message for such common errors is usually not Google's style.

Comment: witch jar do you use for `GooglePlayServicesUtil`?

Comment: The V2 which was released today.

Comment: $Keyboardsurfer if you use Eclipse be sure that your project configured properly. Go to Project Properties -> Java Build path -> Order And Export tab -> set checkbox with your jar. After clean project and refresh to generate new gen. `NoClassDefFoundError` exception might be the reason of that

Comment: I'm building with maven and It's going to be _a lot of fun_ with apklibs again.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Version 2 includes resources and must be imported as a library project. See the instructions at http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html for how to do that in various IDEs.

The resources are for GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(), which directs the user to install, update, enable, etc. Google Play services if it isn't available on the device.

Comment: Not exactly "various IDEs" - it covers Eclipse and the CLI, and that's it.

Comment: If you've included Drive API using Google Plugin, don't forget to delete reference to Google Play Services in the libs folder. Otherwise you'll get duplicate class exception after adding Google Play Services as android library.

Comment: a direct link to the page that resolves the problem:
http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Comment: I was importing this as a `jar` file under the /libs folder (copy paste basically) but what was probably needed is to import this as a library project in order for the R file of the `play-services` to be generated I guess. Thanks for this reply.

Answer (score 34):

I also have the same issues once ,I followed the step properly and able to solve this issue

**First (Set up your project from Google Developer console)**
Go to [API Console - Google Code](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)

Create A project As shown in the images
[image]

Click Create then you will Ask to add a project name as shown

[image]

once you create your project its time to select what service we need to use,In this case we need android v2 map so select the **Google Maps Android API v2** from Service As shown, [image]

Now go to Api Access and create your OAuth 2.0 .By provide your package name and SHA1 fingerprint in the corresponding fields.
[image]

once you finish with OAuth 2.0 we are ready to use your API Key
[image]

Now Create An Android project with the same package name used while creating the  OAuth 2.0. and Check whether you have the **google play service** in Android SDK Manager otherwise install google play service.
[image]

After installing Google playservice you will find a Google play library in Your Android ***YourSdkpath\extras\google\google_play_services***.Import that project to your workspace and give it as the refrence library to your project
[image]

[image]

[image]

After that put the corresponding java and xml files to your project.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package yourpackage;//Package name used while creating the Api key


import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
 import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
GoogleMap googleMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Getting status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    // Showing status
    if(status==ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
    {
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting a reference to the map
        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
    }
    else{

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="yourpackage"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
   <permission
    android:name="yourpackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="yourpackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="yourpackage.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="YourAPIkey"/>
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Add  one more  meta data tag <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    To avoid error   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Answer (score 11):

For Android Studio:

1) Open Module Settings:

2) Add (Import) module google_play_service_lib from SDK

[image: Picture]

3) Module google_play_service_lib check as Library

4) Add library google_play_service.jar from SDK

5) Finish

[image: Picture]

Comment: Following this finally solved the issues I was having in Android Studio. I was making the mistake of either only including the library or creating a module from the wrong directory under google_play_services.

Comment: What about the build.gradle ? Coz, it says that, "Gradle: error: package com.google.android.gms.common does not exist"

Comment: Not working. Followed the steps., But getting Runtime error. 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string'. Please help. I am using Play services 8.4.0

Answer (score 2):

If you already upgraded SDK and get such error remember to:

- use new version of google-play-services.jar if you have copy this file in your eclipse project
- set target=android-19 in *project.properties*
- for newer API (I use API 19) you may need to add following code

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

I also use **ourSdkpath\extras\google\google_play_services** as Eclipse library imported as described above.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error by checking "Copy projects into workspace" while importing the google play services lib.
More info here: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Answer (score 1):

if you are using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
```

change it to individual ones such as

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
```

also add 
`compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` if you have `multiDexEnabled=true`

Comment: You saved me..Thanks ji

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Android Studio when build project without Gradle.
It might be problem with the name of package in AndroidManifest.xml in GooglePlayService project.
It should be **package="com.google.android.gms"**.

Issue appears when I add Library Project as **"New Module"** instead **"Import Module"**.

[image]

When you choose New Module, Android Studio shows dialog to specify "Module name" and "Package name" and by default "Package name" looks like "com.example.MODULE_NAME_YOU_SPECIFED" which is **wrong**. It's very easy to miss it, because project builds with success.

[image]

When you add Library Project by **"Import Module"** everything should be OK, because Android Studio just add project without doing any changes with source code of Library Project.

Comment: Not working. Followed the steps., But getting Runtime error. 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string'. Please help. I am using Play services 8.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I also face same problem. If you run your application in emulator then may be face this error because in most of emulator there is no google playService (Play store app) installed.

So try to run your app in android device which is playService app is installed.

Solution :- add error part code in `try...catch` and then try it will work in emulator also.

Note :- Google Messaging service require palyservice. otherwise throw error `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE`