# Android - Google Maps API v2 - SupportMapFragment Errors

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, android-fragments, google-api

I am trying to get one of my apps back up and running with the Google Maps API v2 for the first time. I created a key for my app in my keystore, extracted the SHA1 hash, acquired an API key, then did the following in-app... I included:

> google-play-services.jar

as well as importing the GooglePlayServices libraryand adding it as a reference to the project. In my Java code I simply just load the layout resource.

```
public class Times extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
    }
}
```

In the layout (res/layout/map.xml) that I am trying to instantiate I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

I also have the following declared in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="tinyTech.us.ua.busschedule.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="tinyTech.us.ua.busschedule.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

And declared in the Application tag of the manifest:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="My_API_Key" />
```

When the activity is loaded, it crashes with the following errors in LogCat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
```

I have attempted to research the problem, however I have been unable to find what I am looking for. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your activity code? You're trying to cast the SupportMapFragment to the non-support version of Fragment as evidenced by the log `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment`

Comment: yes, it because he is using Activity not FragmentActivity as base class for his activities and you can find this in my answer :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to extend `FragmentActivity` if you are using `SupportMapFragment`.
If you are using the `MapFragment` you can extend `Activity`.

Comment: I have the same problem but I'm extending FragmentActivity instead of Activity.

Answer (score 11):

In your layout, use

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/map"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

instead of

```
...    
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
...
```

Answer (score 7):

You must do this:

```
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity{

}
```

Comment: If you can get MapFragment but not SuppoortMapfragment this is why!

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13744765/1215098

Seems like you have to add Google Play services as module, not just as .jar

Answer (score 5):

I solved this error by checking "**Copy projects into workspace**" while importing the Google Play Services lib.
More info here: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem with Google Play Services and everything.. i included as a library and all, and the problem still persisted ("**could not find com.google.android.gms.maps.suportmapfragment**")..

i was able to fix it by:
Going to Project Properties. Then
select **Java Build Path**.
Then Select **Order and Export** tab.
then,
Make sure you check the **Android Dependencies** and **Android Private Libraries**

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I think i had the same problem it seems that newer versions you have to add this line at the manifest

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` in the manifest file.
This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

My case, I add:

File -> New -> Google -> Google Maps Activity

And i follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdCRxEn540U).

Answer (score 0):

I tried evrything shown above but, still i was getting error. So,
downgrade version from `17.1.0`:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.1.0'
```

to `16.1.0`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
```

worked for me!