# Google Maps v2 : how import google-play-service.jar into Android Dependencies

Tags: android, eclipse, android-maps-v2

I have created Google Maps v2 app. I followed the tutorial step by step. And when I'm launching this app.

It show pop up "Unfortunately, Google Maps v2 has stopped".

Here is the logcat...

```
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.achson.googlemapsv2/com.achson.googlemapsv2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at com.achson.googlemapsv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     ... 11 more
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4738)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
09-03 04:51:33.296: E/AndroidRuntime(2148):     ... 21 more
```

I assume that google-play-services isn't inside of Android Dependencies folder.

But it's inside of Android Private Libraries folder. I don't know how to import to Android Dependencies folder. Anyone who knows ? Please share at this.

```
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemapsv2/com.example.googlemapsv2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ac.a(Unknown Source)
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.aV(Unknown Source)
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Unknown Source)
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at com.example.googlemapsv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-06 15:29:30.480: E/AndroidRuntime(1260):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: check ur manifest file ...see if the activity name is mentioned

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611017/importing-google-play-service-library-showing-a-red-x-next-to-this-reference-and/17611095#17611095. how to import the google play services library project. Are you adding it as a jar to your libs folder? You need to reference the library project in your map project.

Comment: see this http://twntee.tumblr.com/post/59576020346/the-maps-api-adding-a-map-to-your-android-project

Comment: There are a number of reasons (and fixes) why this can occur at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726189/android-google-maps-api-v2-supportmapfragment-errors

Comment: also the error is because you are inflating the wrong fragment type

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082851/error-inflating-class-fragment-with-google-map?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming a layout inflation error**

*Primarily caused by inflation of wrong fragment type based on imports.*

**Case 1:** If you are using a `MapFragment` in your FragmentActivity or Activity, using the `import android.support.v4.app.*`(i.e. Your class extends the Activity or Fragment Activity from the this package), then you will get ClassCastException

**Solution** Use a `SupportMapFragment`

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

then use the code to get the map in your Activity.

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) this
                        .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
```

**Case 2:** If you are using a `SupportMapfragment` in your FragmentActivity or Activity ,using the `import android.app.*` (i.e. Your class extends the Activity or Fragment Activity from the this package), then also you will get ClassCastException

**Solution:** Use a MapFragment

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

then use in the code to get the map reference in your Acitivity

```
MapFragment mapFragment = ((MapFragment) this
                            .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
```

Also, the play services need not to be specifically in the Android Dependencies folders, as Android Private folder is too added to your build path.

Comment: i'm not using SupportMapFragment. i'm using MapFragment.      googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

Comment: i've changed. it was launching. but there is no google maps. it just empty on fragment.

Comment: yup. but when i changed to another type of emulator. it displayed button label "Update". It said that google play service must be updated.. blablabla.

Comment: http://twntee.tumblr.com/post/59576020346/the-maps-api-adding-a-map-to-your-android-project see the blog post, I have written about how to run it on emulator, your emulator/devices needs to have latest play services, install them via adb

Comment: yup.. here the logcat said : "error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)"

Comment: @achson that's not an error, actually that is cause of mounted sd card to th emulator

Comment: how many size to be needed ? I try 500 Mb. It didn't run too.

Comment: no.. i mean that error is irrelevent to us with maps not showing up, see if there is any other error, like authentication error because of the api-key, edit yur question and post the new stack trace

Comment: So, should I don't need sd card ? I've posted it above.

Comment: @achson see the new error is due to un intitialisation of CameraUpdate Factory variable

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared the Activity in your manifest?

**Edit:** Once you import library into your workspace (In Eclipse), you right click on the project,  open properties, click android and at the bottom you will see library import section. Add it to that.

Comment: There's something wrong with google-play-service. It doesn't inside of Android Dependencies. Is it the problem  ?

Comment: Have your checked your manifest first? The problem is definitely there. I don't think you declared the Activity(s)

Comment: I suppose not.  It's hard to help when he doesn't post code or reply lol ;)

Comment: sorry @KickAss i'm trying to solve too.. thanks for your help. :D the problem had solved. but it has another problems. :(

Answer (score 0):

What version of API are you using? How does look your xml with the map layout?
I had the same problem recently. And it was caused because I was using wrong fragment type.

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

It worked when I put `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`

then in your code if you work with map you must extend `FragmentActivity` insetad of `Activity` for your class (`public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity`)

```
    GoogleMap mMap;
    SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
    mMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
```

And that is how you get the mapFragment in the code.