# How to return a view from a class using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments, android-view

I have a class (shown below) which extends Fragment. Now i need my class to return a view to the Other class when i create an object. Everything is working fine but i need this class to do the stuff in a background thread.
I also used ASYNC task but i couldn't make an ASYNC task to return a view. can anyone help.??

MapFragment.java

```
public class MapsFragment extends Fragment 
{  
    MapView map;
    LayoutInflater inflater_;
    ViewGroup container_;
    View layout;

    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {  
        inflater_=inflater;
        container_=container;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
        map = (MapView) layout.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        return (LinearLayout) layout;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is too vague. Where do you use the AsyncTask? What View do you want the AsyncTask to return? Post your AsyncTask and what you have tried to do.

Comment: I want to use Async task in above class(MapsFragment) to reurn a view from public View onCreateView() method.

Answer (score 2):

I don't specifically know why you want to pass a View to an AsyncTask, but this is a basic approach:

```
public class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private View view;

    public MyAsync(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Do something, but not with view
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        // You can alter view here or in the other methods with UI access
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

You can also use your own callbacks should this approach not apply to what you want to do.

Comment: i am using this class to return a mapview in my app. Basically i use tabs and when one of the tab is clicked, this class is instantiated to receive the mapview from the tablistener. See my question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741294/how-to-build-an-app-with-actionbar-tab-support-and-mapview