# Android GoogleMaps API ver2 com.google.android.gms.maps doesn't exist

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

i was trying to develop Google Maps using API ver2 and i combined the JAR file for google-play.services.jar, also i tried to make reference on "com.google.android.gms"
but as menthion in API2 Documentation , i have to refere to com.google.android.gms.maps
but it doesn'T exist , can you help me ?
thanks alot

Comment: `com.google.android.gms.maps` is a Java package. You do not "have to refere" to `com.google.android.gms.maps` anywhere that I can think of. You *do* have to refer to *classes* in that package, such as `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment`.

Comment: Then how would you extend SupportMapFragment?

Comment: Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719263/unable-instantiate-android-gms-maps-mapfragment

Comment: Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719263/unable-instantiate-android-gms-maps-mapfragment

Answer (score 1):

You could uninstall extras form SDK Manager and install it agine. That works for me.