# MapView with ActionBar Layout ( API lvl 11 )

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

after some work I was able to instantiate a MapView in a Fragment, I'm using the "Title stripes + swipe" layout, and my goal is to have one fragment with a listview, and the second one with a map.

I've read all the tutorials to have the new google map api workind, got the key and eveything should be settled up, but at execution time i got that error:
**Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: /system/framework/come.google.android.jar:/data/app/my_package**

The code is the one generated by the SDK ( the code generated by eclipse, chosing a title strip + swipe layout ) plus that inside the onCreateView() method:

```
View mFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, null);
MapView map = (MapView)mFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.map);
return map;
```

From the xml side, i have a map.xml layout with only that inside:

```
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that could be wrong.

You may have forgotten to include the proper jars on the build path, or are not referencing a library project correctly, or are missing google play services.

I'd check out this thread for a possible solution.

[Unable instantiate android.gms.maps.MapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719263/unable-instantiate-android-gms-maps-mapfragment)

Comment: Ye, I'm not totally into that to be honest, but:
-Yes, I have downloaded google play service
-I have added the library on the project

So i don't really know what could be, thanks for the link tho

Comment: You made sure to add the library to the build path as well as to the libs folder, right (assuming you're using eclipse)

Comment: And you properly added the library project reference?  http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject