# Embedding google maps android v2 in android

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

i created application in android 2.33 . i used apk v2 keys and i followed all the steps but still its showing error

```
**xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />


**Mainfest**
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.Maps.mappv2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-feature
 android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
 android:required="true"/>

<permission
      android:name="com.Maps.mappv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.Maps.mappv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission            android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.
     permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


   <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
         <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="mm" />
    </activity>
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
      android:value="AIzaSyA64MFhpngQBkXP5__fvHeLE0xAXWKwfgU"/>
  </application>

</manifest>

**Activity**
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
```

i included google-play-services jar library file but still it showing un expectedly           stoped...

```
 **The error are**
  12-22 20:51:59.344: E/Trace(698): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4663)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at com.Maps.mappv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-22 20:52:00.165: E/AndroidRuntime(698):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-22 20:52:39.734: E/Trace(724): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4663)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at com.Maps.mappv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-22 20:52:40.244: E/AndroidRuntime(724):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-22 20:52:49.084: E/Trace(738): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4663)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at com.Maps.mappv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-22 20:52:49.624: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: did you make a new project at https://code.google.com/apis/console/ , added the api access and got the right key (android, not browser)? I copied your code, made a new project on https://code.google.com/apis/console/ and added google maps android api v2 (watch out, there's another google maps api v2 that's not for android), I used my api key and it works fine...

Comment: i tried but still it showing same error...will it run in emulator?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719263/unable-instantiate-android-gms-maps-mapfragment
here it get's the same error, try making a project in your Eclipse (if that's your IDE) by importing the google-play-services. And then go to preferences in your project, Android, and add that google-play-services-project as library

Comment: i followed all the steps but same error

Answer (score 3):

Try **clean build** both the Library Project and Normal projects First. Is not worked check the following :

> i included google-play-services jar library file

You don't have to include the jar. You have to import as **android library project**.

1. Import the library project in your workspace
2. Add it to your project as library
3. Then build the app

Reason:
The library project has some xml resources. So the project cannot be imported as jar.

[image]

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  com.google.android.gms.R$styleable

As log says styleable cannot be referenced as you haven't built resources.

The R file is a generated one.

From jar u cannot get reference to

1. Drawables (images)
2. xml resources [Styles, Strings etc.]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Android 2.3.3 you need to use `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment` and `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`.

In the `onCreate` of your activity you can add the `SupportMapFragment`...

```
    SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: You need to make sure you are adding the Google Play jar AND [src as part of your project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719263/unable-instantiate-android-gms-maps-mapfragment).