# Android - Google Maps API v2 - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, google-maps, noclassdeffounderror, google-maps-android-api-2

I try to run Google Maps with Intellij IDEA 12.

I already tried advices:

- [Embedding google maps android v2 in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004289/embedding-google-maps-android-v2-in-android/14626708#14626708)
- [Google Maps Android API v2 Authorization failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696620/google-maps-android-api-v2-authorization-failure?rq=1)
- [Unable instantiate android.gms.maps.MapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719263/unable-instantiate-android-gms-maps-mapfragment/13744765#13744765)
- [Google Maps Android API gives a NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792148/google-maps-android-api-gives-a-noclassdeffounderror)

and so on. But unfortunately that doesn't work for me.

My configuration:

1) real device htc wildefire s, android 2.3.5

2) [image]

3) `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
      <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              package="ru.ergeslab.TransportScheduleYaroslavl"
              android:installLocation="auto"
              android:versionCode="1"
              android:versionName="1.0">
        <uses-feature
                android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
                android:required="true"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <permission
                android:name="ru.ergeslab.TransportScheduleYaroslavl.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="ru.ergeslab.TransportScheduleYaroslavl.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
        <uses-sdk
                android:minSdkVersion="10"
                android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
        <application android:label="@string/app_name">
            <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                    android:value="MY_KEY"/>
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
            <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                      android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

4) `MainActivity:`

```
<pre>
package ru.ergeslab.TransportScheduleYaroslavl;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }


}
```

5) `main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

6) IDE project settings:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Full Android logcat:

```
04-02 21:27:07.718: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:250)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1712)
        at ru.ergeslab.TransportScheduleYaroslavl.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1794)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the maps library jar as a dependency or the lib project folder as a dependency?

Comment: Using only the jar is not sufficient. You should be using the library project as a whole. I don't know how to do it in IntelliJ. But, the question link you mentioned has almost everything you will need.

Comment: @KumarBibek I use google-play-services_lib as dependency lib. Look at shoots

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally ran my application!

I didn't edit manifest, layout and activity, just updated project settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I hope this will help someone.

Comment: @EmilAdz I don't really know:) Full update of my project maybe

Comment: Yes thanks! I had to add the project as a dependancy and then add a reference to the UnusedStub to force intellij to import the dependancy. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 4):

**1.** Remove this permission from the manifest file:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

it's part of Google Maps API V1 and not needed in Google Maps API V2.

**2.** Move the meta-data part to be right before the closing application tag:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="MY_KEY"/>
</application>
```

**3.** Regenerate a new key and register it via the Google API Console and make all the process again.

Comment: 1 removed

2 moved

3 regenerated with keytool (but SHA is the same as before) and then run app.

But the same error.

Comment: By 3 I meant remove the debug.keystore folder and compile some project this will create a new SHA1 key and register it via the Console.

Comment: Thanks for help. I generated a new sha1 and new API key, but error persists :(

Comment: Omg, I finally run my application! So, I can tell that advices unfortunately are not works for me:(

Answer (score 2):

#### Follow these directions first

For the sake of completeness of documentation, download and get your keys and project setup.

[Installing the Google Maps Android v2 API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api)

### The IntelliJ Specific Part

#### The Modules

1. Import the google-play-services_lib as a module into the project.

   `${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib`
2. Now make sure it is set as a Library module

   [image]
3. Go into your project settings and make sure you add the module as a dependency. Take note of the folder icon.

   [image]
4. Add the `google-play-services.jar` as a library to your module and one of the Android support modules if you plan to support older devices. Most people use `android-support-v4.jar`, but in my example I used `android-support-v13.jar` which includes everything in v4. This is where you get support for `Fragment` on older phones.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace in yout `main.xml`

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

at

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't usually put google-play-services_lib inside libs folder.

Try importing it as a library project. http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/09/android-library-projects-support/

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and i just needed to set the SDK for the library project of the `MapsApiV2` to `Android 2.3.3 (API lvl 10)` (maybe 2.2 will work as well.