# Android Adding Maps v2 API to Master Detail Flow - Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to add a Google Maps view using the version 2 API to the built in Android Master Detail flow.  For some reason I am getting a error inflating class fragment exception:

```
    12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class fragment
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at com.reading.trackitparent.MapDetailFragment.onCreateView(MapDetailFragment.java:52)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
12-29 22:47:05.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1655):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
```

I have created a new MapDetailFragment:

```
package com.reading.trackitparent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.reading.trackitparent.dummy.DummyContent;

/**
 * A fragment representing a single Item detail screen. This fragment is either
 * contained in a {@link ItemListActivity} in two-pane mode (on tablets) or a
 * {@link ItemDetailActivity} on handsets.
 */
public class MapDetailFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the item ID that this fragment
     * represents.
     */
    public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";

    /**
     * The dummy content this fragment is presenting.
     */
    private DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public MapDetailFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
            // Load the dummy content specified by the fragment
            // arguments. In a real-world scenario, use a Loader
            // to load content from a content provider.
            mItem = DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(
                    ARG_ITEM_ID));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_detail,
                container, false);

//      // Show the dummy content as text in a TextView.
//      if (mItem != null) {
//          ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail))
//                  .setText(mItem.content);
//      }

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

and I am trying to use the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ItemDetailActivity" >

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ItemListActivity:

```
package com.reading.trackitparent;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

/**
 * An activity representing a list of Items. This activity has different
 * presentations for handset and tablet-size devices. On handsets, the activity
 * presents a list of items, which when touched, lead to a
 * {@link ItemDetailActivity} representing item details. On tablets, the
 * activity presents the list of items and item details side-by-side using two
 * vertical panes.
 * <p>
 * The activity makes heavy use of fragments. The list of items is a
 * {@link ItemListFragment} and the item details (if present) is a
 * {@link ItemDetailFragment}.
 * <p>
 * This activity also implements the required {@link ItemListFragment.Callbacks}
 * interface to listen for item selections.
 */
public class ItemListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ItemListFragment.Callbacks {

    /**
     * Whether or not the activity is in two-pane mode, i.e. running on a tablet
     * device.
     */
    private boolean mTwoPane;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);

        if (findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {
            // The detail container view will be present only in the
            // large-screen layouts (res/values-large and
            // res/values-sw600dp). If this view is present, then the
            // activity should be in two-pane mode.
            mTwoPane = true;

            // In two-pane mode, list items should be given the
            // 'activated' state when touched.
            ((ItemListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.item_list)).setActivateOnItemClick(true);
        }

        // TODO: If exposing deep links into your app, handle intents here.
    }

    /**
     * Callback method from {@link ItemListFragment.Callbacks} indicating that
     * the item with the given ID was selected.
     */
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
        if (mTwoPane) {
            // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
            // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
            // fragment transaction.
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putString(MapDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
            MapDetailFragment fragment = new MapDetailFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();

        } else {
            // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
            // for the selected item ID.
            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, ItemDetailActivity.class);
            detailIntent.putExtra(MapDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
            startActivity(detailIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

I have referenced the Google Play Services Libs.  My manifest looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.reading.trackitparent"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.reading.trackitparent.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.reading.trackitparent.permission.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.reading.trackitparent.ItemListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.reading.trackitparent.ItemDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_item_detail" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ItemListActivity" />
        </activity>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />

</manifest>
```

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: You have to add the Google Play lib AND the src dir needs to be part of your project; not sure which IDE you are using or I could point you to examples on SO.

Comment: Using Eclipse - how do I add that in?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719263/unable-instantiate-android-gms-maps-mapfragment/13744765#13744765) is the SO question that touched on it, note the answer from Guilherme Muniz.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace `MapFragment` with `SupportMapFragment`. `SupportMapFragment` is the one to use with the Android Support package backport of fragments. `MapFragment` is for the native API Level 11 version of fragments.

Comment: Thank you - I have done both of these things.  I am know getting a NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable both in an emulator and on my Xoom tablet.  It looks as though isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() is returning 1, although I have checked that Google Play Services are install from the Play Store.  Any ideas?

Comment: Update: Fixed the previous error, but back to the Error Inflating Class Fragment issue again.  I changed MapFragment to SupportMapFragment in the layout xml as suggested.

Comment: @JamesCross: Consider posting a fresh stack trace to your question.