# Android java.lang.SecurityException with requestLocationUpdates

Tags: android, location, securityexception

Currently I try to implement Mock location for my Android Test Application, this is my class for Mock location :

```
public class MockLocationProvider {
    String providerName;
    Context ctx;

    public MockLocationProvider(String name, Context ctx) {
        this.providerName = name;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.addTestProvider(providerName, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, 0, 5);
        lm.setTestProviderEnabled(providerName, true);
    }

    public void pushLocation(double lat, double lon) {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location mockLocation = new Location(providerName);
        mockLocation.setLatitude(lat);
        mockLocation.setLongitude(lon);
        mockLocation.setAltitude(0);
        mockLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        lm.setTestProviderLocation(providerName, mockLocation);
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.removeTestProvider(providerName);
    }
}
```

And this is my code located in a test function for push the fake location :

```
MockLocationProvider mock = new MockLocationProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, context);
mock.pushLocation(-12.34, 23.45);
LocationManager locMgr = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener lis = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //You will get the mock location
    }

   @Override
   public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

   }
};
locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, lis, Looper.getMainLooper());
```

My problem is the requestLocationUpdates function, if I don't write "Looper.getMainLooper()" I get a Runtime exception, But now if I put this parameter, I have a Security exception. Who can help me please ?

The exception :

> java.lang.SecurityException: invalid package name:
>   com.example.myapp.test
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546) at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499) at
>   android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:582)
>   at
>   android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:867)
>   at
>   android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:490)
>   at
>   com.example.myapp.ApplicationTest.testLoc(ApplicationTest.java:220)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
>   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263) at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
>   at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300) at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) at
>   org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222) at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300) at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157) at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136) at
>   android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:54)
>   at
>   android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:228)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1853)

Comment: Have you define the needed permissions on the manifest? You should also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474761/java-lang-securityexception-invalid-package-name-com-google-android-gms

Comment: In my case, the error had to do with the context (I was passing the test context, instead of the target context). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35190090/1621402

Answer (score 0):

You get different exceptions becuase if two different errors.
The runtimeexception that you get when calling the the method without the proper looper is a "wrong thread exception" that you are trying to do UI work from a non ui thread, or the other way around. The security exception is because you probably didnt set the permissions correctly.