# Programmatically setting genymotion gps during testing causes "SecurityException: invalid package name" when setting latitude

Tags: java, android, genymotion, android-testing, android-securityexception

When testing, I am setting the lat long via Genymotion like so:

```
 package com.mypackage.name;

 public class TestGps extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyClass>{

    ... //setup just calls super.setup();

    public void testLocationButton(){
       Gps gps = GenymotionManager.getGenymotionManager(getInstrumentation().getContext()).getGps();
       gps.setStatus(Gps.Status.ENABLED);
       gps.setLatitude(40.7127); // the error happens here
       gps.setLongitude(74.0059);
   }
}
```

I get the following issue when run:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: invalid package name: com.mypackage.name
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:582)
at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:867)
at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:490)
at com.genymotion.api.Gps.waitForTargetLocation(Gps.java:271)
at com.genymotion.api.Gps.setLatitude(Gps.java:134)
```

Comment: Use `getTargetContext()` instead of `getContext()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a test `Instrumentation.getContext()` returns the context of the **tests**. To access the context of the app being tested, you need to call `Instrumentation.getTargetContext()` instead. You should also consider using [`InstrumentationRegistry`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/InstrumentationRegistry.html). This is now the preferred access point for `Instrumentation` instances.

Comment: Damn! That was fast, and it worked! 

And, I will start using InstrumentationRegistry from now on. 

Thank you so much!

Comment: @alotofquestions Just to clarify, `InstrumentationRegistry` is only available in the [Testing Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html).