# google maps android api v2 error

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing an app. on SDK 17 which involves google maps but the problem is that when I use **Google Maps v1 api key**, the map works fine but when I try to use **Google Maps android V2 api key** nothing is displayed (only the google maps tiles appear). I have included the google play services library and searched for all possible reasons but couldn't find one. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

1)Go to the Google APIs Console https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:650847076763

```
2)In Services enable ‘Google Maps Android API v2’ and agree to the terms
3)In the left navigation bar, click API Access.
4)Click Create New Android Key....
```

Comment: I have already got the correct api key from the apis-console yet it is  still not working.

Comment: have u followed all the necessary steps..?

Answer (score 0):

Google maps api V1 is already deprecated use the maps api V2 instead.

Documentation page:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Here is a quick start guide:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/19xKLZTrY1l6Sgu-V_IVSDIRZrcThjwxDrlm9rNr0tzo/edit

If you are having problems with MapFragment or the google play services library visit this thread it will help you.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/19xKLZTrY1l6Sgu-V_IVSDIRZrcThjwxDrlm9rNr0tzo/edit

Also I answered related problem that you have here.
[How to/Error in declaring google-play-services-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991967/how-to-error-in-declaring-google-play-services-component/14992298#14992298)

Happy coding :)