# Android Map Certifivate Fingerprint. (MD5):

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

So I am trying to do a map application on android.

I wrote this code on my mac os terminal to create Certificate fingerprint

**keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android**

code generate:

**(MD5): C9:C1:40:66:40:07:D0:8C:FF:44:A3:7D:F4:73:57:4B**

I don't know why but code generate MD5 not SHA-1
and I understand I need **20** character finger print but my terminal generated **16** character.

if my fingerprint is wrong how can I create true one. If its true than how can I create Api key for map from developer.google.com

If do you have any clue please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add -v in the end of the keytool command that you gave. It might look something like this.

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android -v
```

UPDATE:

I answered somewhat related problem like this before, you might get an idea from it if my answer is not enough for you. :)

[How to/Error in declaring google-play-services-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991967/how-to-error-in-declaring-google-play-services-component/14992298#14992298)

Answer (score 0):

Install plug in eclipse
 http://keytool.sourceforge.net/update
Go to eclipse -> Help -> Install new software paste above link

and install it

and then open keytool in ecipse open keystore option will be provided 
it will give you SHA1 finger print.

(keytool window will be opened  beside errorlog and logcat
click drop down and then androiddebugkey click it you will have all the info there)