# App with Google Play Services lib froyo is not getting installed?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I've just started off with Google Play Service and am stuck at the google play lib integration. I've tabulated my steps below.

Steps followed:

1. Update SDK to latest.
2. Install Google Play Service for Froyo (or Android 2.2)
3. Copied SDK dir/extras/google/google_play_services_froyo/libproject/google-play-services_lib to ~/google-play-services_lib_froyo/
4. Ran android update lib-project -t android-8 -p google-play-services
5. cd google-play-services_lib_froyo
6. ant clean debug

At this point `build.xml` is ready.

Now setting up MyApp to use library

7. Executed android update project -t android-8 -l google-play-services_lib -p MyApp -n MyApp. Please note target is Froyo here too.
8. ant clean debug

I finally get the MyApp apk. On attempting to install on my JellyBean 4.1.1 tab, the installer gives a App not installed message. Id like to know what is the correct way to do such that my app get installed with google play services support.

I have followed the instructions above from android site itself but applied to Froyo version of google play.

Comment: add `logcat` messages or the error message you see. Can you try installing from command line `adb install -r myapp.apk` see what it displays.

Comment: Im dont debug with logcat, rather see the code. Il definitely look at going the logcat way. The app is run on the device which is not visible in linux (I run debian). So, il try to run it on an emulator and post back. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: you can see `logcat` on debian with `adb shell logcat -d`. Clear the log with `adb shell logcat -c`, try install the app, try again `adb shell logcat -d`

Comment: tried it. got following messages. Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]

Comment: i used logcat as u instructed and it reports - Package requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.gms; failing; I remember adding a uses-library declaration in the manifest, before compiling for android froyo. Ive specified the same shared library package there.

Comment: Ok. So I removed the uses-library element for package com.google.android.gms of manifest and app installs properly. Even google play services is initialising properly when apk loaded on jellybean phone. As per setup details of google play, xml element is not even compulsory. @ashoke thanks for your guidance.

Comment: @ashoke kindly post your answers so I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debug your apk installation with logcat

- Clear the log with `adb shell logcat -c`
- install the app,
- `adb shell logcat -d` to see the error messages in logcat

Looks like you are using `com.google.android.gms` in `uses-library`. Technically, [it is not a valid `uses-library` item,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658608/error-when-uses-library-com-google-android-gms)  for future reference.