# com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsFragment could not be instantiated

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I got this error in my layout file with MapFragment

I tried

- Installing Google Play Service, but still have error
- Following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25839336/could-not-find-class-com-google-android-gms-maps-supportmapfragment) still does not work

My application is able to run, but when I open a Fragment with MapFragment application stopped working

Full error

> **Rendering Problems**
>
> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>
> - com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>
> Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to
>   skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.
>
> If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.
>
> **Exception Details**
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet)
>
> - at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
> - at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
> - at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
> - at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
> - at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
> - at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
> - at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
> - at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
> - at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>
> Copy stack to clipboard

fragment_contact.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="layout.ContactFragment">


    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ng.anthony.mininavigationdrawer" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <activity
            android:name="com.th.ac.sd.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    0
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.th.ac.sd"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
}
```

Installed SDK tools

[image]

Comment: You should be using support map fragment, by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tools:context="layout.ContactFragment">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
```

You have a Fragment in a Fragment.

Android doesn't really like that, so wherever you put `<fragment class="layout.ContactFragment">` (assuming you did), you can replace that with a Google Map Fragment since the only view you have in this `ContactFragment` is a Map Fragment anyway.

Otherwise, you can use a `FrameLayout` and dynamically load a `new SupportMapFragment` just like any other Fragment.