# Google Map API v2 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps

I am facing  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment` error while integrating `Google Map API V2`.

I have tried almost all possible solution present on stackoverflow.

```
10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mapdummy/com.mapdummy.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:268)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1837)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at com.mapdummy.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    ... 11 more
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:581)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:549)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4240)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    ... 20 more
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:571)
    10-01 15:02:48.181: E/AndroidRuntime(14917):    ... 23 more
```

**Manifest file:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.mapdummy"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="12"
            android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.mapdummy.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.mapdummy.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAY5MKF9nca8Y4LQUv6Zj3N1wuKr8ikJUs" />
            <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="false" /> 
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

**XML File:**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/the_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

**Java Code:**

```
package com.mapdummy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your manifest file and xml file here.

Comment: @prakash I have added google-play-services_lib as library project

Comment: post ur java code...

Comment: check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719263/unable-instantiate-android-gms-maps-mapfragment

Comment: @prakash have already tried all solutions present on this link still no succes.

Comment: just correct way to add your google play service lib in you project,got you the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

try out by replacing your map fragment in xml by this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Issue is in your xml file defining class name in fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is the way you added google-play-services to your project:

I have copied the google-play-services.jar in libs folder and set in the build path of eclipse.

This is wrong! Read the first 3 steps of this blog post I wrote to get an idea of how to do it correctly:

Google Maps API V2

In short, you should import google-play-services as a project in your workspace. and then reference it from your project.

Comment: I have imported google-play-services as a project in my workspace and then have added it as a library

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolve my issue. Issue occurred because Eclipse was not able to find google-play-services_lib(even it was showing green mark while adding as a library). I tried same process on another machine and everything worked fine.

So I changed my entire Android SDK location and it woked fine.