# Simple Intent to change activity not working

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to change activity by an intent like this to a fragmentactivity that opens a embeded Google Map:

```
Intent driver = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DriverActivity.class);
startActivity(driver);
```

But the app crashes, I've recently moved from Eclipse on my Windows to a Eclipse on Ubuntu. I can't see why the app won't change activity. The debugger opens layoutInflater.class and the message inside that windows is: **Source not found**

What's wrong and how do I fix it?

```
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:262)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at com.codele.blackcab.DriverActivity.onCreate(DriverActivity.java:51)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
07-04 19:47:09.828: E/AndroidRuntime(30884):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you playing on an emulator with google api?

Comment: By the way, don't use getApplicationContext() for this sort of thing... instead use a current context, like an Activity.

Comment: @PozzoApps I'm using an physical device to debug and deploy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372391/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-rstyleable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
Intent driver = new Intent(this, DriverActivity.class);
startActivity(driver);
```

Comment: Not working, I'm getting `07-04 20:20:26.138: E/AndroidRuntime(3953): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable` but my class is registered in the manifest

Comment: Make sure you have that class present in your activity file..Clean your project build once and try to rerun it.