# Error importing "google-play-services_lib" in IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, google-plus

Am trying to add Google+ sign in to my app, and i understand i have to add `Google Play Services` to my project libraries.So i followed the steps provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960315/importing-google-play-services-lib-into-intellij-idea-12) StackOverflow question, but when am done i get the error

`Gradle: module 'google-play-services_lib' won't be compiled. Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java module and Android-Gradle module in one project.`

To show i have followed the instructions correctly, this is what i have done.

1. I opened `Project Structure`.
2. Clicked on `Modules` in the left tab, then the `+` button.
3. Selected `import modules` in the drop down menu
4. Navigated to the location of the google play services_lib folder which in my case is

   `..\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib`
5. clicked on my project (Still in project structure) and then opened the `dependencies` tab on the right. Clicked the `+` button and from the drop down menu selected `Module Dependencies` and selected `google-play-services_lib` from the list of libraries.
   Then i clicked the `+` button again and selected `jars or directories` from the drop down menu and then navigated to.

`...\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\google-play-services.jar`

I have tried rebuilding the project and even restarting IntelliJ, but the problem still persists.Any help?

Comment: Is your android project - gradle project?

Comment: I guess it is, i followed the steps in creating a new project in intelliJ.Should it be a gradle project? Because there is an option for specifying that there.

Comment: Do you have `build.gradle` file in the root folder?

Comment: Yes i do.And the project is in fact a gradle project

Answer (score 0):

After conversation in comments I figure out your situation:

1. So first remove module for google play services that you added manually.
2. Add next line into your `build.gradle` inside `dependencies` block (took example from https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/4Yhpn6p9icf):

   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'

And don't forget to sync project with gradle file!

Comment: IntelliJ does not have the `sync project with gradle file` option.

Comment: Try to re-import project again