# Google Admob sample manifest file error

Tags: android

I am triying to run google admob sample application but It shows error on "@integer/google_play_services_version". Is there a library I need to add other than android.jar, annotations.jar and google-play-services.jar?

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Comment: need to add `google_play_services.lib` module as a dependency.

Comment: Go to this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843784/google-play-services-library-update-and-missing-symbol-integer-google-play-serv?rq=1[](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843784/google-play-services-library-update-and-missing-symbol-integer-google-play-serv?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding the play services jar, add the google-play-services_lib project to eclipse (I assume you're using eclipse) and then add that project to your own project as a library.

it's described in the setup: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html - step 4 in section 1.

for intellij users: [Importing google-play-services lib into Intellij IDEA 12 (and 13)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960315/importing-google-play-services-lib-into-intellij-idea-12-and-13)

Comment: The problem is I am not using Eclipse but Intellij Idea. And When I remove services.jar and add services.lib All code gives error.

Comment: Here is how to add services.lib to Intellij Idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960315/importing-google-play-services-lib-into-intellij-idea-12-and-13. Pls add to your answer :)