# Android Studio project with library module google play services error

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-library

I'm having this problem that so many devs do:

```
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').
```

What's different about my project is the play services dependency comes from a library (that I control) which I've included as an AAR file.

**Library**

build.gradle: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1'`

manifest: `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

**App project**

Top level build file:

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
```

The AAR is in the `libs` directory.

Module build file: `compile(name:'app-debug', ext:'aar')`

That is the only dependency.  I also tried it like this:

```
compile(name:'app-debug', ext:'aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
```

but no change.  That was based on this question, which is the closest I've found to my situation, but that person is including the dependency as a maven artifact: [Error with google_play_services_version value from aar library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31989691/error-with-google-play-services-version-value-from-aar-library)

Please let me know if you need to see anything else.

Comment: Try to check these SO question [23923933](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923933) and [29567138](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567138) if it can help you.

Comment: @KENdi Nothing relevant that I haven't tried already in those.

Answer (score 0):

Local aar file doesn't include dependencies of the project, so you should include all dependencies (including google location services) used by library manually to app's build.gradle file.

Comment: I didn't downvote the answer, someone else did. And asking this, is not nice.