# Google Ads_Error in LogCat

Tags: android, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, logcat

I want to add my project android Google advertising . He did all of this [example](https://github.com/diha-o/Service_Get/blob/master/Error).I add all libraries, all as described there.But after compiling and attempts to launch an application on my phone get it is not clear to me the problem in the debugger(*IDE-Intellij Idea*).

**I add in manifect:**

```
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
         android:value="17"/>
```

and

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

**I add in main class(onCreate):**

```
 AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

**And in .xml:**
     `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.dd_pc.service.ServiceActivity"`

and

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

And this is log error in link([github](https://github.com/diha-o/Service_Get/blob/master/Error)).

Comment: Your error log link is pointing to the AdMob website, please correct it or add the log to your question

Comment: @MBat, yeah, fix it, i'am sorry/

Answer (score 0):

According to your error log, you need to import the Google Play Services library to your project.

You can find instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) and since you are using Intellij Idea, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17977734/1333516) are specific instructions that may be useful.

Comment: I imported a bug climbs since the imported library. I imported both .jar file and an entire folder and connected to the project.

Comment: and i don't have file `build.gradle` in my project((

Comment: did you follow all the steps described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17977734/1333516 ?

You still have the same error as before

Comment: yeah, i see and do like this, and have this errors(

Comment: Have you considered switching to Android Studio?
It's based on Intellij Idea, but you'll have a much easier time integrating this kind of stuff