# Android old devices crashing on start

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, sdk, android-support-library

My android app is crashing on older devices, it crashes as soon as it press run.  I cannot work out where the error is, and if I put breakpoints it appears to crash before any of them fire. Here is the logcat...

```
05-19 08:10:53.847 7782-7788/com.appname.appname I/dalvikvm: Debugger is active
05-19 08:10:53.851 7782-7782/com.appname.appname I/System.out: Debugger has connected
05-19 08:10:53.851 7782-7782/com.appname.appname I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-19 08:10:54.055 7782-7782/com.appname.appname I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-19 08:10:54.255 7782-7782/com.appname.appname I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-19 08:10:54.455 7782-7782/com.appname.appname I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-19 08:10:54.655 7782-7782/com.appname.appname I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-19 08:10:54.855 7782-7782/com.appname.appname I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-19 08:10:55.059 7782-7782/com.appname.appname I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-19 08:10:55.259 7782-7782/com.appname.appname I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-19 08:10:55.459 7782-7782/com.appname.appname I/System.out: debugger has settled (1419)
05-19 08:10:55.463 7782-7782/com.appname.appname W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 10394 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
05-19 08:10:55.463 7782-7782/com.appname.appname D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0012
05-19 08:10:55.467 7782-7782/com.appname.appname I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.AppOpsManager.checkPackage, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzb
05-19 08:10:55.467 7782-7782/com.appname.appname W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 134: Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;.checkPackage (ILjava/lang/String;)V
05-19 08:10:55.467 7782-7782/com.appname.appname D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0011
05-19 08:10:55.467 7782-7782/com.appname.appname I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzi
05-19 08:10:55.467 7782-7782/com.appname W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 495: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
05-19 08:10:55.467 7782-7782/com.appname.appname D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
05-19 08:10:55.559 7782-7782/com.appname.appname I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
05-19 08:10:55.559 7782-7782/com.appname.appname I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
05-19 08:10:55.567 7782-7782/com.appname.appname W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 10394 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
05-19 08:10:55.567 7782-7782/com.appname.appname D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x000c
05-19 08:10:55.567 7782-7782/com.appname.appname D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-19 08:10:55.567 7782-7782/com.appname.appname W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4c35648)
05-19 08:10:55.571 7782-7782/com.appname.appname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.zza.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.zza.zzaR(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzn.zziJ(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzz.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzaa.zzDj(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.zzaT(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1214)
                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1189)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4879)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4485)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4425)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Specify the Android Version Please

Comment: What version of android does the apk target? and *define* old devices, *android versions preferably*!

Comment: presumably the app is build using latest SDK that targets Lollipop and later, running it on Jellybean/ICS/Gingerbread will fail with a crash.

Comment: It Seems Google Play Services Library is Crashing as it is unable to found any required Method or Class

Comment: I was using a phone which I no longer am, but I am using genymotion simulator, which is using APK 18

Comment: the logcat, is that from the Samsung Galaxy S3 or the genymotion simulator?

Comment: It is on the simulator, the only big change to the code from when it was working is I upgraded from retrofit 1 to retrofit 2

Comment: You're using a class not available on older Android versions. Check your Android Studio warning and you'll probably found a warning saying this.

Comment: Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Did you find a warning like this?

Comment: Where do I see android studio warnings?

Comment: In the right of the screen, where is the scrollbar. You'll find there warning, errors or things like this

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have not added **google-play-services_lib** project as library in **Libraries** (under Modules). If you have, you can go to Libraries and simply remove it. Google Play Library Should Not Appear In Libraries.

**make sure you have no duplicate libraries**.

**For example**,

If you are using SDK of Facebook it has it's own support library in it's libs folder. If you are using support library in your project then compiler throws error. Solution is, point your project and Facebook (and other modules if you have) to a (one) support library

check answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372391/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-rstyleable) for more details.

Comment: I dont have anything called google-play-services but I have many play-services libraries, such as play-services analytics

Comment: Have you checked above link answers ?

Comment: Yes I have been working through them, nothing yet, but havnt tried everything, back on it this morning.

Comment: try answers from that link. it will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks I am on it, will give you plus tick when i get it

Comment: I had some reactive x libraries that I deleted and now the problem has disappeared.