# Google map is not showing in my Android App

Tags: android, android-maps

i am developing an android app that shows Google map. My log cat is showing following errors. I am new in android development. Please help me out. Thanks

```
03-06 06:31:25.561: E/dalvikvm(2476): Could not find class 'com.example.mapdemo.BasicMapActivity', referenced from method com.example.mapdemo.MainActivity.<clinit>
03-06 06:31:26.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2476): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 06:31:26.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2476): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-06 06:31:26.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-06 06:31:26.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
03-06 06:31:26.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
03-06 06:31:26.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
03-06 06:31:26.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-06 06:31:26.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-06 06:31:26.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-06 06:31:26.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 06:31:26.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-06 06:31:26.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-06 06:31:26.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 06:31:26.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-06 06:31:26.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-06 06:31:26.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-06 06:31:26.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 06:31:26.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2476): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.mapdemo.BasicMapActivity
03-06 06:31:26.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     at com.example.mapdemo.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:98)
03-06 06:31:26.253: E/AndroidRuntime(2476):     ... 15 more
```

Comment: show your code to the people here. Then only they would be able to help you out.

Comment: add google_play_services library in your project. refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691028/noclassdeffounderror-at-google-play-services-v2-library

Answer (score 0):

You should include this`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` in your application tag in the manifest and also include this permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have defined your activity "BasicMapActivity".
2. Check if it has also being included in the manifest.xml