# android maps v2 offer play service

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, google-play-services

I have sucessfull working android maps API v2, but then i tried to test if i dont have Google Play services, will app offer to install it.

So i uninstalled Google Play services and my application is crashing now. Its not offering to intall Google Play services like it does in Sample App. In LogCat its printing `Google play services is missing` and after `NullPointerException`. In sample app i didnt see any code that handles that, i guess its inculded in map library. Im using `SupportMapFragment`, however in sample app its also used.

How to make app offer install play services like its in sample app ?

Comment: this link will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691028/noclassdeffounderror-at-google-play-services-v2-library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `GooglePlayServicesUtil` class for that. Your code will look something like this:

```
int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) 
{
    // Google Play Services installed correctly, continue
} 
else if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING ||
         resultCode == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED ||
         resultCode == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED) 
{           
    // Google Play Services not installed / too old / disabled.
    // Show dialog to install or update
    Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, 1);
    dialog.show();
} 
else 
{
    // Something else went wrong, handle this yourself
}
```

The `getErrorDialog` method will show the dialog that directs the user to the Google Play Store to install or update Google Play Services.