# Crash when trying to call "GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable"

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

So, I installed everything, linked the project folder and my app crashes when I try to check the services.

Any hoop I forgot to jump on this stupidly over-complicated system just to display a simple map with some markers on my app?

All I get is "07-06 20:01:43.132: E/AndroidRuntime(1348): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil", even if I try to execute it inside a try-catch, it will still crash the app.

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691028/noclassdeffounderror-at-google-play-services-v2-library

Comment: No it doesnt, see the image, all that stuff is set.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project and rebuild?

Comment: please add all the relevant code for how you are checking whether google play services is available

Comment: tony, its just that on the image. A button call the seeMap method and I check it. The button is working, because it prints anything before the isgoogleplayservicesavailable.
peshkira, just did that, still crashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen an app crash the same way before, but it only did because the google-play-services folder was added to the project in the Properties - Java Build Path section instead of including it as an android library in Properties - Android section.

Comment: Yeah, I found out the library must be added too and the .jar must be checked for exportation.

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly made this P.O.S work. Instead of doing all dumb crap googles tells you, just add a variable that points to their google-play-services.jar. But I think doing things simple is too mainstream for those hipsters.