# Android application not loading map view

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi I am developing simple android application in which I am using android mapV2. So on Google API console I created one project after than I created new key for my application. So my application manifest looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.maptestapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
    android:name="com.example.maptestapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.maptestapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.maptestapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Goolge API Key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyC7945EdDYMoMHZAYNvNXbVSl1NSZrWCfs" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So I am defining permissions and also defined meta data. and In layout I am trying to display

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Now I tried to display my activity it shows me following error :

```
12-24 22:59:54.345: E/Google Maps Android API(28739): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
12-24 22:59:54.345: E/Google Maps Android API(28739): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.example.maptestapp, API Key: AIzaSyZAYNvNXbVSl1NSZrWCfs, Certificate Fingerprint: 096388A528A6F8347914D
```

Its not rendering any map view. Need help. Thank you.

Comment: `LogCat` is your friend. No need for any answers here.

Comment: yeah but i checked all things but its not working :(

Answer (score 1):

please try the link below  which show step by step description ,which show how to use google map v2.[Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691028/noclassdeffounderror-at-google-play-services-v2-library/14686856#14686856)

Answer (score 0):

Your API key is wrong. The error explains exactly what you need to do:

Please see
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start 
for how to correctly set up the map.

Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: 
Package Name: com.example.maptestapp, 
API Key: AIzaSyZAYNvNXbVSl1NSZrWCfs, 
Certificate Fingerprint: 096388A528A6F8347914D