# Android Google MapV2 doesn't work on intellijIdea

Tags: android, google-maps, intellij-idea, google-maps-api-2, google-play-services

This is my main class

```
    package com.example.mapv2example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                .title("Hamburg"));
        Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(KIEL)
                .title("Kiel")
                .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

        // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Android Manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.mapv2example"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="17"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
            android:name="com.example.mapv2example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapv2example.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             >
        <activity
                android:name="com.example.mapv2example.MyActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="MY_API_Key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and the main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

I am works on IntellijIdea 12 and I add android support library and google play services but when I try to run my app emulator "unfortunately,mapv2example has stopped" I get map version 2 api key from google also this is my error log

```
   12-26 09:03:12.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1714): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mapv2example/com.example.mapv2example.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.mapv2example.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
        ... 11 more
12-26 09:03:12.996: WARN/ActivityManager(298): Force finishing activity com.example.mapv2example/.MyActivity
12-26 09:03:13.043: WARN/WindowManager(298): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (328x583) to layer 22010
12-26 09:03:13.652: WARN/ActivityManager(298): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41896338 u0 com.example.mapv2example/.MyActivity}
12-26 09:03:24.261: WARN/ActivityManager(298): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{41896338 u0 com.example.mapv2example/.MyActivity}
12-26 09:08:13.061: INFO/Process(1714): Sending signal. PID: 1714 SIG: 9
12-26 09:08:13.071: INFO/ActivityManager(298): Process com.example.mapv2example (pid 1714) has died.
12-26 09:08:13.111: WARN/InputMethodManagerService(298): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41c4dd88 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@41b7fd80
12-26 09:10:33.132: DEBUG/dalvikvm(435): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 511K, 19% free 3041K/3752K, paused 540ms, total 540ms
12-26 09:20:33.401: INFO/ActivityManager(298): No longer want com.android.exchange (pid 1420): empty for 1804s
12-26 09:21:33.782: INFO/ActivityManager(298): No longer want com.android.browser (pid 1511): empty for 1810s
12-26 09:21:33.844: INFO/ActivityManager(298): No longer want com.android.calendar (pid 1495): empty for 1811s
12-26 09:21:33.897: INFO/ActivityManager(298): No longer want com.android.sharedstoragebackup (pid 1531): empty for 1809s
12-26 09:21:41.868: DEBUG/GCM(490): Ignoring attempt to send heartbeat on dead connection.
12-26 09:23:08.892: DEBUG/dalvikvm(298): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1142K, 38% free 7504K/12064K, paused 113ms, total 128ms
12-26 09:26:45.921: INFO/EventLogService(490): Aggregate from 1388066205680 (log), 1388066205680 (data)
```

Comment: what's at line 23? I also use Intellij IDEA and have faced problems while using Google Maps in it. The main reason is because of importing the libraries incorrectly.

Comment: this question here will help you understand problems faced while developing app using Google Maps http://stackoverflow.com/q/13691028/1979347 and this answer here is specifically for Intellij IDEA http://stackoverflow.com/a/17153855/1979347

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile properly the google play services in your build.gradle... you can follow the steps at the android developers site... http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html... and maybe you will have to use the gmaps api v3...

regards...!!