# E/AndroidRuntime(8592): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, android-fragments

Well, i'm trying to add google map to my application but i'm having those errors

```
04-17 16:25:07.169: E/AndroidRuntime(8592): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
 04-17 16:25:07.169: E/AndroidRuntime(8592): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.guide_oran-1.apk]
```

My main activity :

```
package com.example.guide_oran;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Activity_map extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.gmap);
    }
}
```

my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
 />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be caused by your `Activity` extension and your layout which has **only** a `fragment` class. You need to extend your activity with `FragmentActivity` to allow the activity to deal with fragments. That being said, you also need to change your fragment class to support `SupportMapFragment`.

```
public class Activity_map extends FragmentActivity {
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.gmap);
       // find the fragment and commit it into this activity
       SupportMapFragment mapfragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
       // initialization of googlemap
       googleMap = mapfragment.getMap();

       // It might be resumed by:
       // googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    }
}
```

Then instead of `class="com...MapFragment"`, you need to change the `class` of the fragment to:

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

You can see multiple tips for the same issue on: [Unable instantiate android.gms.maps.MapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719263/unable-instantiate-android-gms-maps-mapfragment)
Also, find [a complete and detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14686856/2668136) to use Google Maps, step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your fragment inside a Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) you can found a good tutorial

Comment: The actual problem is he's using an `Activity` instead of a `FragmentActivity` (as pointed out by @Filo below)